# Saving a composite image as a new image

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, png, html2canvas

I'm helping make a webpage that creates a unique composite image by overlaying a bunch of different .pngs on top of each other in different colours and opacities. The next step is to save the result as a single image file that can be shared.

My first port of call was such packages as html2canvas.js and dom-to-image.js. html2canvas was erroring for me and while I was able to get dom-to-image to work more quickly, it isn't giving me the composite coloured image, just one "layer" of that image by the looks of things.

I wondered if anyone could visualise how something like this would need to work, and advise on the most effective way of converting a bunch of overlaid .pngs into a single entity that can then be easily saved as an image?

Comment: Have you considered drawing the different .pngs to a single canvas element  and then saving the canvas as an image using `canvas.toDataURL()`? Note that canvas supports different opacities, and you can probably manage different colors using the canvas compositing options.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. This did seem to be the most plausible route, but it's really nice to get a sanity check from other/wiser heads.